# Add data to gridview and then retrieve it and add to a database

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, gridview

I am doing an academic project. For that need help in a form.. in billing form.

First of all I will show you my two tables connected to this operation.. I can't add hyperlinks and photos because I am a new user.. so.. pls add http:// infront of image links below..

**Items** table:

[image]

**Sales** table:

[image]

And here's my demo layout of my form

[image]

In the form you can see a dropdowlist. In that list I bound the `item_code` from `item` table ... when load form all items will load in that dropdownlist..

Next is a textbox... it is to enter our quantity of item we purchased... that we want to enter at that time...

Then you can see a button called `ADD TO DATA GRID`. When the user clicks on it, I want to add a row to the gridview that contains `item_code` which we selected before from the dropdowlist and `quantity` which we entered in the textbox..

And I want to add 3 more columns to the gridview, `size`, `item_name`, `tax`.. these items I want to fetch from the `items` table using

```
select size, item_name, tax 
from items 
where item_code like '" + dropdownlist.selecteditem + "';"
```

I think you got it what I said... and I think it's clear what the `Delete` button should do.. when I click on it, I want to delete that specific row...

Next you can see a label.. total.. there want to add the `price*quantity` which we adding to grid.. means if I added a item and that have price 50 and quantity 2.. the total will be 100 then I added another item have price 20 and quantity 2 then add 40 (20*2) to total then total will be 140(old 100 + 40)..like that...

And finally you can see a button called `final submit`.. when pressing this button... want to add the the one by one row to `sales` table from gridview and some data want to fetch from the `items` table.. means in gridview only have `item_code,name,price,size` and `tax`.. when click on `final submit` button want to add whole 9 fields of `items` table to the `sales` table, one by one have in gridview.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `DataTable` and link it to `DataGridView`, fetch database data into DataTable and update any changes made to GridView to DataTable and then Update to database using that DataTable

```
GridView.DataSource=DataTable;
GridView.BindData();
```

After you made change to GridView update them to this DataTable using a BindingSource or just use for loop and then update to database

Comment: bro..i cant understand bro...can you pls...give vode of aspx and aspx..pls..bro.it will be apriated

Comment: No one can give you complete code check for grid view insert edit update and delete http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/anjudidi/select-update-and-delete-data-in-a-Asp-Net-gridview-control/